# Oracle sql Pivot financial indexes by ID and date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, pivot-table

I am basing my question on this tutorial (Oracle pivot sql): https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1

I have a database with prices for indexes (stock market related) which have a price for each day. I need to select the data so It groups the index prices by date and creates a column for each individual index.

My DB looks like this:

[image]

And I need this:

[image]

I have tried following

```
  SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT name, price_date, price
        FROM   ibsecmprch)
PIVOT  (GROUP(price_date) as pricedate FOR (name) IN ('A' AS a, 'B' AS b, 'C' AS c))
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: what happens after you try it??

Comment: 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Comment: Why do you need this? The only reasonable use is for reporting purposes; for further processing, the way the data is stored currently is much more appropriate than the pivoted version. And for reporting, the pivoting is much better done in your reporting application - you have much more control over formatting. This is not to say you can't pivot in SQL, it's just to ask WHY.

Comment: I need it for a Jaspersoft Report, the line chart has to be presented with the data structured like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
... pivot ( max(price) for name in ('SP500' as SP500, 'DOW' as DOW, 'DAX' as DAX) )
```

(etc.)

Comment: with "max(price)" I get: ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier

Comment: @DavidDunham - Probably caused by your `ORDER BY` clause. How do you want to order your output `BY NAME`?? There is no more `name` in the output. You probably want to order by `price_date` anyway.

Comment: how would I add a column with 1,2,3 etc. (rownum does not work) to it?

Comment: @DavidDunham - Assuming you want it ordered by date, in the outer select add `, row_number() over (order by price_date) as rn`

Comment: cannot get it to work, SELECT *, row_number() over (order by price_date) as rn
FROM   (SELECT symbol, price, price_date
        FROM aade_pivot_test4)
pivot ( max(price) for (symbol) in ('SP500' as SP500, 'DOW' as DOW) )
ORDER BY price_date .... or SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT symbol, price, price_date
        FROM aade_pivot_test4)
pivot ( max(price) for (symbol) in ('SP500' as SP500, 'DOW' as DOW) )
ORDER BY price_date, row_number() over (order by price_date) as rn;

Comment: Two problems with that query. When you add columns to SELECT, you can't SELECT *, you must either give the column names or you must precede * with a table or subquery alias. (It is always best to name the columns specifically.... in this case SP500, DOW, ..., PRICE_DATE, in whatever column order is appropriate.) Second, in the ORDER BY you don't need (nor should you) repeat the ROW_NUMBER() function, just include `rn` in the order by. You can't give an alias in ORDER BY, nor should you need to. And, there is no point in including `rn` in ORDER BY anyway, since you are already ordering by date.